# awk: Built-in FILENAME variable on empty file

Tags: awk

Why does `awk`'s FILENAME variable return nothing when input is a empty file? Does this means `awk` doesn't open that file? If doesn't open how knows it's empty, or if it's open why doesn't return filename then?

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33555908/4023950), but there not explained why below should work.

```
awk 'BEGINFILE{print FILENAME}1' filename
```

and below doesn't.

```
awk '{print FILENAME}' filename #or
awk 'BEGIN{print FILENAME}' filename
```

Comment: A good question. See the following and see `FILENAME` pagagraph: http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_11.html  I quote `Inside a BEGIN rule, the value of FILENAME is "", since there are no input files being processed yet`

Comment: Thanks, there I can see mentioned "FILENAME is "", since there are no input files being processed yet". With considering this apart of if it's in BEGIN or not, means FILENAME set when not in BEGIN and a input file specified not depending on "if file has a field" as below [Nd64's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399546/72456) points and as I tested it depends on if a file has a field but not documented.

Comment: To elaborate on my previous comment. Since the `BEGIN` statement is ran **before** anything, at that moment `FILENAME` or any other built in variable like `NR` or `NF` is undefined/empty.

Comment: My suggestion: try experimenting with `awk '{print "Line " NR " of " FILENAME}' test.txt`, for files with different numbers of lines.  How many times does it print for an empty file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the `awk` manual:

```
FILENAME  A  pathname  of  the  current input file.
Inside a BEGIN action the value is undefined.  (...)
```

I think this is the explanation.  Until a field is processed the value of `FILENAME` is undefined. Since no field is processed in case of an empty file the variable stays uninitialised.

Comment: thanks, this _"Until a field is processed the value of FILENAME is undefined"_ should be updated in `awk`'s man page at least.

Comment: Agree!  By the way, I checked the source and could not quickly see why it should be uninitialised... Well, we have seen that apparently it is so.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the last paragraph of this answer, but I don't think it's right. `FILENAME` is defined as soon as each file is processed (before it even knows whether it's empty or not), so it's always set in `BEGINFILE`. But it's not defined before then, so you wouldn't expect it to be set in `BEGIN`.

Comment: s/field/record/. An empty file contains no records _and_ no fields, but `{print FILENAME}` works fine for an empty _record_  with no fields; it is only the absence of a record that causes the action to not be executed.

Comment: `{print FILENAME}` works fine, but it prints `N` times for a file with `N` records.  There should be no confusion about how many times it prints for a file with zero records.
And just to be clear, `FILENAME` is defined as soon as the `BEGINFILE` block executes, which happens before the first byte/field/record is processed, and I suspect before it attempts to open the file.

Answer (score 3):

*Note: parts of this answer are specific to GNU `awk`, specifically [4.0](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2011-06/msg00013.html) and later, which added [`BEGINFILE`/`ENDFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html#BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE)*

### Per-line block

```
awk '{print "File name: " FILENAME}' myfile
```

This will print `File name: myfile` once for every line in myfile.  If myfile is a blank file (zero bytes), it will contain no lines, and so the above string won't be printed at all.

### `BEGINFILE` block

```
awk 'BEGINFILE{print "File name: " FILENAME}' myfile
```

If supported, this will print `File name: myfile` once, before processing any lines.

Otherwise, if not supported, it will probably treat `BEGINFILE` as a falsy conditional expression, and print nothing at all.

### `BEGIN` block

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "File name: " FILENAME}' myfile
```

This block is evaluated happens before the any of the files are processed, and at this time the value of `FILENAME` is [not defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html).

The [`gawk` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#Auto_002dset) specifically defines it as `""` though, so we can know there it will just print `File name:` .